# How can I limit the queryset using a parent field?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've to LIMIT by a parent model field.

## models.py

```
class Blog(Model):
    max_posts       = IntegerField(verbose_name=u"Limite Posts", help_text=u"Número de posts máximo DESSE BLOG para serem exibidos na home.")
    
class Post(Model):
    title           = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u"Título")
```

And I want to get something like this on my template:

**- Blog A (max_posts=2)**

```
Item 1

Item 2
```

**- Blog B (max_posts=3)**

```
Item 1

Item 2

Item 3
```

So I tried this on my views

## views.py

```
Post.objects.annotate(blog__max_posts=Count('blog__max_posts')).filter(blog__published=True)
```

But it doesn't work like expected. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to make the query on the `Post` model? Thanks.

Comment: First retrieve the max number of posts for the given blog. Then use it to limit the queryset. BTW shouldn't the Post model be related to the Blog model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the missing foreign key:

```
class Blog(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255)
    max_posts = IntegerField(verbose_name=u"Limite Posts", help_text=u"Número de posts máximo DESSE BLOG para serem exibidos na home.")

class Post(Model):
    blog = ForeignKey(Blog)
    title = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u"Título")
```

you can fetch the posts with one db-hit per blog:

```
blogs = Blog.objects.filter(published=True)
posts = {b:b.post_set.all()[:b.max_posts] for b in blogs}
```

you might want to add an `order_by` before slicing..

The template can then e.g. be written as:

```
{% for blog, blogposts in posts.items %}
    <h1>{{ blog.name }} (max_posts={{ blog.max_posts }})</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for post in blogposts %}
       <li>{{ post }}</li>  {# probably something more fancy here.. #}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Looks like the best solution. But I'm still not finding a way to loop this posts on template.  I'm getting the following result:
https://dpaste.de/coNo
So when I do "for post in posts" my results come with Blog instead of Posts as expected.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how you would use this in a template.

Comment: On this same example, how can I keep the blog order? 
blogs                           = Blog.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('order')
Doesn't work because of the for on the next line I guess.

Comment: To keep the order you can use a `collections.OrderedDict` (you'll need to import it): `posts = OrderedDict([(b, b.post_set.all()[:b.max_posts]) for b in blogs])`.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that django provide you such built in feature, so you need to handle it buy own. To do that define `ForeignKey` relations in `Blog` model:

```
class Blog(Model):
  # Other fields 
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Achieve desired result by adding `add_post` method to `Blog` model:

```
def add_post(self, post):
    # assume you have max_posts_count defined
    if self.post_set.count() >= max_posts_count:
         raise Exception("Too many posts")

    self.post_set.add(post)
```

Other way to achieve same result is to use [Django pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-save) to check whether `posts` count reached maximum value, if it's `raise Exception` within pre_save method or allow saving.

Answer (score 0):

> put a ForeignKey field on Post related to Blog.
>
> use validators on that field `validate_max_posts` as follows:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Blog(Model):
    max_posts = IntegerField(verbose_name=u"Limite Posts", help_text=u"Número de posts máximo DESSE BLOG para serem exibidos na home.")

def validate_max_posts(value):
    blog_id = None
    if type(value) is not Blog:   # admin panel
        blog_id = value

    if type(value) is Blog:       # service : DRF
        blog_id = value.id

    post_count = Post.objects.filter(blog__id = blog_id).count()
    max_posts = Blog.objects.get(pk=blog_id)
    if post_count > max_posts:
        raise ValidationError(u'Exceed max posts count')

class Post(Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u"Título")
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog,validators=[validate_max_posts])
```

Comment: I don't want to limit the model, doesn't look like a good idea as I just want to limit on front-end.